# SQL Server 2011 vs. SQL Server Denali

Tags: discussion, tags, sql

I'm wondering what the process should be for guiding the tag people should be using for the next version of SQL Server. With CTP3 now out in the public's hands, I expect StackOverflow, ServerFault and others to see some increased volumes around this version.

Currently most of the questions I see are tagged "denali" or "sql-server-2011."

I'm not sure it's a great idea to perpetuate the code-name, since that will not be the marketing name. Similarly we do not tag questions about SQL Server 2005 "yukon", SQL Server 2008 "katmai" or SQL Server 2008 R2 "killimanjaro."

And it is pretty clear given that no TPC results have been published yet that the release of the next version of SQL Server is more than 6 months out. Even if it were less and it does magically release this year, it would be highly unlikely to be named SQL Server 2011, simply because it would be "last year" almost immediately after release.

So, just curious how the tags develop, and what kind of guidance or influence the site provides to users other than just going in and re-tagging questions and suggesting changes manually.

**EDIT** at the PASS Summit keynote this morning, the official name for "Denali" was announced : SQL Server 2012. Not sure exactly how this changes the existing tags and migrations, but I suspect [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) makes the most sense. As recently suggested on dba.stackexchange.com, [denali](/questions/tagged/denali) should be a synonym and [sql-server-2011](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2011) should be renamed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now, go with [sql-server-denali](/questions/tagged/sql-server-denali) or [denali](/questions/tagged/denali) (the former is better, in my mind, though it's currently unused), because that is the only name we know.  Guessing here would be counter-productive and confusing.  Then when the official name comes out, make that a new tag and make all the [denali](/questions/tagged/denali) tags synonyms of it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I did not know you could make synonyms here (though I do use that feature in SQL Server quite a bit).

Comment: Unfortunately there is not enough volume yet on the tag for anybody to have enough score to suggest or vote on a synonym. I guess I just need to wait it out.

Comment: If there's a tag you think should be a synonym of another tag, you can post a request here, but what tag would you be proposing?  [denali] -> [sql-server-denali]?  You can just edit the posts that have [denali] for now.

Comment: I'm proposing that both denali and sql-server-2011 should be mapped to sql-server-denali (for now) and then later to <the official release name>. The problem with denali on its own is that, as you allude to, it is not specific enough - the hash tag #denali on twitter gets all kinds of noise about the GMC SUV and the national park. Not that that confusion will happen on SO or SF but consistency is king.

Comment: There is an argument against doing that, in that questions related to "denali" could speak about features or bugs that are not present in Sql 2011 RTM for instance.