# Add "sql-server-denali" tag to synonyms for "denali" and "sql-server-2011"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Since SQL Server "Denali" is not likely to be called SQL Server 2011, I'm a little nervous that when the true name is released the questions tagged [sql-server-2011](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2011) will get lost in the shuffle. I've tried to casually encourage use of a more generic tag [sql-server-denali](/questions/tagged/sql-server-denali) but in almost all cases they end up getting re-tagged back to the former by other users. What I'd like to propose is the tag [sql-server-denali](/questions/tagged/sql-server-denali) for now, which - along with [denali](/questions/tagged/denali) and [sql-server-2011](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2011) - will later become a synonym for, most likely, [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012).

For more background on this request, please see [SQL Server 2011 vs. SQL Server Denali](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98692/sql-server-2011-vs-sql-server-denali)

Comment: Sounds like we just need to synonymize [tag:sql-server-2011], [tag:sql-server-denali], and [tag:denali]. They should all refer to the same tag, [tag:sql-server-denali].

Comment: Well that's the thing - it won't be called "SQL Server Denali", it will be called SQL Server 2012 most likely. We didn't keep "SQL Server Yukon" for SQL Server 2005, or "SQL Server Katmai" for 2008, or "SQL Server Killimanjaro" for 2008 R2. Why would we keep "SQL Server Denali" in the long term?

Comment: Fine, then don't keep it. The problem is that we don't know what the official name will be yet, so the best option we have is Denali. When we *do* have the official name, we'll create another synonym and make `[sql-server-20xx]` the official tag. We do this all the time for version-specific tags. I don't see why this situation should be any different. The tag synonymizer works *really* well.

Comment: Sorry, I think we're on the same page, I just took your comments as in the long term we should keep SQL-server-denali as the "parent" tag if you will. I have no issues with using that tag in the meantime but I think it should be merely an alias once the official name is known. I apologize for not having extensive knowledge into how the synonymizer works, I just see a lot of tag abuse/misuse out there today.